# Help changing shower cartridge to unknown shower faucet

Tags: plumbing, shower

[image][image][!.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtTux.jpg)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtTux.jpg)

[hello this is my first time here I was wondering if anyone know how to remove this stem? I posted on another post that had a similar shower faucet but my post was removed

Comment: I imagine using two wrenches should work.  One pipe to hold the pipe steady, and one to turn the nut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to grasp the valve base pipe with a pair of adjustable pliers, Channellocks, being careful not to damage the threads. Then take an adjustable wrench and fit it around the nut on the valve stem and turn the wrench counterclockwise. You can then remove the valve stem and replace the washer or replace the entire valve stem.

Comment: Wow thank you so much I appreciate the tip.